# How to merge two HashSet of complex types and keep duplicates from second set?

Tags: c#, hashset

I have a complex type as:

```
class Row : IEquatable<Row>
{
    public Type Type1 { get; }
    public Type Type2 { get; }

    public int dummy;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var type1HashCode = Type1.GetHashCode();

        //djb2 hash
        unchecked
        {
            return ((type1HashCode << 5) + type1HashCode) ^ Type2.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    // Equals method also overrided
}
```

I have a HashSet<Row> and I want to merge it with another HashSet with two different strategies; first I want to merge and keep duplicates from main HashSet, I tried `main.UnionWith(second)` now I want to merge main with second (result being in main) and keep duplicates from second one; How can I do that? (it's a performance critical code)

**My code:**

```
var main = new HashSet<Row>()
{
    new Row(typeof(int), typeof(long))
    {
        dummy = 10
    }
};
var second = new HashSet<Row>()
{
    new Row(typeof(int), typeof(long))
    {
        dummy = 20
    }
};

// Merge here.

Trace.Write(main.First().dummy) //I want 20
```

**I expect `main.First().dummy` to be 20.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second strategy can be implemented by calling `main.ExceptWith(second);` first and then `main.UnionWith(second)` like the first strategy.

Since the `UnionWith` is basically a shortcut for

```
foreach (var element in second)
    main.Add(element);
```

and `ExceptWith` - a shortcut for

```
foreach (var element in second)
    main.Remove(element);
```

the second strategy can also be implemented with a single loop:

```
foreach (var element in second)
{
    main.Remove(element);
    main.Add(element);
}
```

But I think the performance gain would be negligible compared to `ExceptWith` + `UnionWith` approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to keep duplicated values after merging. In this scenario, HashSet is the wrong data structure for your objective.

From the MSDN documentation for HashSet(T):

> A HashSet collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements. If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the List class together with the Sort method.

Comment: I want main duplicate elements removed, and duplicates from second one added to main

Comment: It doesn't matter about which duplicates are preserved and which aren't in a HashSet, you'll end up with the same result. Additionally, HashSet is not ordered, so you can't expect an element to be first. I really think you're looking for the List<Row> data structure...